# List of all available groovy functions in Nexus3

Tags: groovy, nexus, nexus3

Where can I find the groovy API documentation containing the list of available function for Sonatype Nexus 3?

I saw the web page below which describes

- core
- repository
- blobStore
- security

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/script-api/writing-scripts#app

... but how to know what to put after security, for example security.securitySystem.changePassword?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I too had looked for the specific functions for a while but didn't find any official documentation, so I went straight to the code looking for the functions:

- [core](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/708db207b87daadd1066c24ca578beba4af3bb53/components/nexus-core/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/internal/provisioning/CoreApiImpl.groovy)
- [repository](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/708db207b87daadd1066c24ca578beba4af3bb53/plugins/nexus-script-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/script/plugin/internal/provisioning/RepositoryApiImpl.groovy)
- [security](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/b399b4bf04f37d9acc3b2e70b4a62aa84ba81faa/components/nexus-security/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/security/internal/SecurityApiImpl.groovy)
- [blobStore](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/708db207b87daadd1066c24ca578beba4af3bb53/components/nexus-core/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/internal/provisioning/BlobStoreApiImpl.groovy)

Here are some samples that may help: https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples/tree/nexus-3.x/scripting.

The links were taken from this page: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/scripting.html#scripting-configuration

Answer (score 1):

You should read the code itself, a good start would be [Nexus3 Cookbook](https://github.com/criteo-cookbooks/nexus3) since it has explanations from the Nexus3 Cookbook and examples.

For API examples you can read up on them at [API Examples](https://github.com/dhoer/chef-nexus3/tree/master/api_examples).

Answer (score 1):

1. System > Tasks > Create Task of Type : Admin - Execute Script.
2. - Task name: Get all repo methods
   - Language: groovy
   - Source:

     ```
     log.info(
        repository.getClass().
          declaredMethods.
            findAll{ !it.synthetic}*.name.join(', ')

     )
     ```
3. Run the Task
4. Check logs in : Support > Logging > Log Viewer